# php not updating password nor token in the d.b

Tags: php

My forgot password is not updating the token table nor is it updating the password when changes it keeps echoing the error message below is the form code:

```
Forgot Password</strong></h3>
      <form name="forgot" method="POST" id="forgot" action="includes/reset.php">
        <div align="center">
          <table width="372" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="181"><p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p><strong>Password</strong></p></td>
              <td width="181"><span id="sprytextfield1"><br />
                <label for="label"></label>
                <input type="password" name="passsowrd" id="password" />
                <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Your password is required</span></span></td>
</tr>
            <tr>
              <td><p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p><strong>Confenter code hereirm Password</strong></p></td>
              <td><span id="spryconfirm2">
                <label for="password"></label>
                <input type="password" name="password2" id="password" />
                <span class="confirmRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="confirmInvalidMsg">The values don't match.</span></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
    <div align="center">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table width="98" border="0">
        <tr>
          <th width="44" scope="row"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" /></th>
          <th width="44" scope="row"><input type="reset" name="clear" id="clear" value="Clear" /></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
      <table width="372" border="0">
        <tr> </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
```

and the reset.php is:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$token=$_GET['token'];
include("settings.php");
connect();
if(!isset($_POST['password'])){
$q="select email from tokens where token='".$token."' and used=0";
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
   {
$email=$row['email'];
   }
If ($email!=''){
          $_SESSION['email']=$email;
}
else die("Invalid link or Password already changed  <a href='../index.php'>Click here to go back to the HOME PAGE<a/>");}

$pass=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_SESSION['email'];

if(isset($_POST['password'])&&isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
$q="update registration set password='".md5($pass)."' where email='".$email."'";
$r=mysql_query($q);
if($r)mysql_query("update tokens set used=1 where token='".$token."'");echo "Your password is changed successfully  <a href='../index.php'>Click here to go back to the HOME PAGE<a/>";
if(!$r)echo "An error occurred";
    }
```

so the issue is the following error message is echoed all the time:
Invalid link or Password already changed.

what should i do also if i add:

```
if(!isset($pass)){
echo '<form method="post">
enter your new password:<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Change Password">
</form>
';}
```

then it works but opens it in new blank page which is un professional thats y am trying to add it to the html

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection and you should not be using deprecated mysql.  Sanitize your input and use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: but sanitizing does not solve the issue right??

Comment: Correct, thats why I chose to post a comment instead of an answer

Comment: i add:

if(!isset($pass)){
echo '<form method="post">
enter your new password:<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Change Password">
</form>
';} 
then it works but opens it in new blank page which is un professional thats y am trying to add it to the html

Answer (score 0):

Your `else die` is in the totally wrong place.  You are always going to die because while will always evaluate to false as the loop ends.

If your intent was to die if the query fails you should do something like:

```
$r = mysql_query($q);

if (false === $r) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
   ...
}
```

Of course my general advice is to not use mysql functions at all, as they are deprecated with PHP 5.5.  You also should make sure you are explicitly handling all the possible outcomes for you queries and log meaningful errors to help you debug.

Comment: @systemsengineer If you don't want you script to `die()` every time you run it, then, yes, you should change it.

Answer (score 0):

You have no token being passed in the code you presented

```
$token=$_GET['token'];
```

where is that token coming from in the script, it is not calling it from the database,

```
$q="select email from tokens where token='".$token."' and used=0";
```

also you are not guarding against any sql injection, that should really be addressed, unless I missed the part of the code where the token was being sent to the reset page, if so my apologies

```
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
   {
$email=$row['email'];
   }
If ($email!=''){
          $_SESSION['email']=$email;
}
else die
```

flowing down your code you run the query to select email where the token would be blank, i assume no email is returned so if the email is not blank do this, or else die... it must die because the the $email is blank

Comment: $token=$_GET['token']; where is that token coming from in the script, it is not calling it from the database, $q="select email from tokens where token='".$token."' and used=0"; but is using it to call the email from the database... and further it is not being checked for sql injection.

Comment: its okay yes u r missing the token from being sent coz its in another location so dont worry

Comment: have you tried to echo the token to verify it is making it to that page?

Comment: it is making it to the page the but everytime i hit submit the error keeps getting echoed:  Invalid link or Password already changed. also the token is not used

Comment: change:
$q="select email from tokens where token='".$token."' and used=0";
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
$email=$row['email']; }
If ($email!=''){ $_SESSION['email']=$email; }
else die("Invalid link or Password already changed  <a href='../index.php'>Click here to go back to the HOME PAGE<a/>");}

to:
$q="select email from tokens where token='".$token."' and used=0";
echo "the query is ".$q."<br><br>";
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
$email=$row['email'];
echo "the email is ".$email."<br><br>"; }
If ($email!=''){ $_SESSION['email']=$email; }}

Comment: the query is select email from tokens where token='' and used=0 does that means the token isnt being fetched

Comment: so now what do u suggest but it is showing on the web browser

Comment: if i add if(!isset($pass)){
echo '<form method="post">
enter your new password:<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Change Password">
</form>
';} then it works but opens it in new blank page which is un professional thats y am trying to add it to the html

Answer (score 0):

I was going to edit your post, but there were so many formatting and syntax issues I'll post it as an answer instead.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);

    include 'settings.php';
    connect();

    $token = $_GET['token'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    if (isset($pass) && isset($token)) {
       $q = 'SELECT email FROM tokens WHERE token=' . $token . ' AND used=0';
       $r = mysql_query($q);

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
            $email = $row['email'];
        }

        if ($email != '') {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email; // Why?

            $q = 'UPDATE registration SET password=' . md5($pass). ' WHERE email=' . $email;
            $r = mysql_query($q);

            if ($r) {
                mysql_query('UPDATE tokens SET used=1 WHERE token=' . $token);
                echo 'Your password is changed successfully <a href="../index.php">Click here to go back to the HOME PAGE<a/>';
            } else {
                echo 'An error occurred';
            }
        } else {
            die('Invalid link or Password already changed  <a href="../index.php">Click here to go back to the HOME PAGE<a/>');
        }
    }
```

This shnould get you on the right track, please take note of tabs, curly braces and **most importantly**, be consistent in how you write code. Stick to single **or** double quotes, **always** use curly braces even on single line if/else statements.

*However, as others have said, this code is still highly insecure and deprecated, but it should work.*

Comment: thanks for the awnser pier but now am getting an error on line 33 which is the last curly brace

Comment: you did and thanks for the fix but i mean there is an error literally on line 33 and yet the same echo: Invalid link or Password already changed Click here to go back to the HOME PAGE

Comment: There is no error on line 33, it's just fine in my IDE. We aren't here to debug your code.

Comment: There, made some more adjustments. You really need to learn more on coding before going any further though.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your `while` block too soon. Move the `}` below the `die`